# How can we call functions from other controllers in a play scala controller

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

In Play Scala 2.5 application, I define my controller like-

```
 class Application @Inject() (ws:WSClient) extends Controller{
```

Now, I want to call a function `readConfig()` of another controller class-  ConfigReader
Is there any way to do this, if i am not using services for this particular use cases of sharing functions in controllers?

In play 2.4, with controllers as objects, I could easily do it with `Appliation.readConfig()`. How can we do this with controllers as classes ?

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to call another controller, you might want to question your architecture: controllers are not supposed to contain logic. You may be better off creating an additional class (that is not a controller) with shared logic that you can use in both controllers. Among the benefits are: testing, you can do something with the result (if you're calling a controller from a controller, the result will be a `Result`)

Comment: @rethab, Now, I made a separate services pacakge with a class(DataOperations) containing functions which are to be shared by the controllers.A function- readConfig(),in this, would need to read a json file using play's classLoader. Should i use DataOperations as a class or declare it as an object?Given, this function would require Environment object get current application context. Could you suggest me an efficient appraoch as to how can I call functions of DataOperations in Application controller?

Answer (score 0):

Just inject the controller instance:

If you have:

```
class ConfigReader @Inject() (ws:WSClient) extends Controller {
  def readConfig() = ???
}
```

You should be able to inject it into other controllers:

```
class Application @Inject() (ws:WSClient, configReader: controllers.ConfigReader) extends Controller {
  def get() = Action {
    configReader.readConfig()
  }
}
```